# Webpack - How to resolve module recursively

Tags: reactjs, webpack

This is my folder structure

```
project
  |app
     |component
       |Header.js
       |Home.js
     |sass
       |header.scss
  |node_modules
     |moment
```

This is how I want import modules in Home.js

```
import Header from 'Header'
import 'header.scss'
import moment from 'moment'
```

How to config webpack so that it understand what module I'm trying to import?

Comment: Aren't you afraid of module names conflict if you build dynamically `modulesDirectories`? You can get erros pretty quickly and nasty to debug.

Comment: webpack will notify when there is duplicated. And the solutions to that is explicitly import one of the same name with paths. Or rename the duplicated to something else more meaningful, it's good to name component more specific anyway.

Comment: How would webpack tell the difference between a module installed via npm and a "local" (for lack of a better word) module? How would a colleague know? Or future you? If you're looking for a way out of relative path import hell I would probably rather look at [babel-root-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-root-import) if you're using babel or something similar if you're not but that's just my 5 cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it. Gonna have to manually add more directory in the array when there is new one.

```
resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: [
        'app',
        'app/component',
        'app/sass',
        'node_modules',
        'bower_components'
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying relative paths in the import statements. moduleDirectories is not intended to list out every directory, only the roots.

Your import statements should probably look like this: (Assuming they are accessed from in `app/`)

```
import './component/Header'
import './sass/header.scss'
```

Then moduleDirectories only needs to include 'app', not subfolders thereof.

Comment: I just want to import without the paths. Do you have any suggestion for doing so?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at use Babel aliases

https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-alias

And configure something like this:

```
{ "src": "./app/component", "expose": "component" }
```

Then

```
import Header from 'component/Header';
```

Answer (score 1):

This link should help:

http://xabikos.com/2015/10/03/Webpack-aliases-and-relative-paths/

But essentially if your `webpack.[production/dev].config.js` file is in `/project` it will need an `alias` section within a `resolve` section; something like this:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./app/component/Home.js"),
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
       alias: {
           moment: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/moment/moment.js')
       }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this

https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve

and do necessary configuration in your webpack to resolve paths in runtime